# How to allow everyone to see the list of books in FireBase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security

I have an activity to register and log in my app,after that user can add a book(title,descreption...).

I have also an activity that contains a listView of books. this activity is the home page,I want allow everyone to see it ,even for people not logged in.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".AccueilActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

How can I allow everyone access to this activity ,and keep the rule security `"auth != null",`to add book and other actions?

Rules that I have in FireBase Database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Node Book:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create node specific rules like the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "books" : {
      ".read" : "true",
      ".write": "true"
    }
    "$other" : {
      ".read" : "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

Here `database.rules` requires no authentication, whereas the rest do require authentication (governed by $other).

Comment: `otherData` reference to what ?

Comment: I'm just giving you an example of how you can achieve different authentication types at different nodes of your database. 'otherData' is just a placeholder

Comment: You're almost there @MehmetKologlu: if you change `otherData` to `$other` it will work for all children except for `books`. But be sure to try it though, because Ive never used `$other` like that for read permissions.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I wasn't using it to refer to the rest but rather just another node, but that is a better way, thank you. I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @Amal Has this solved your problem? Mind giving feedback to my answer?